# Python having issue reading my csv file, keeps giving error and I don't know why

Tags: python, csv

i'm using python to analyze a csv file of a stock and i'm getting this error, why is this happening? I was told maybe it's because there is no header called Close but there is, I was also told The header may have some trailing white spaces, so i added code in the python file to get rid of any issues like that but i still get this error.

[image: Error that i'm getting]

[image: This is the csv file when loaded into python, I see no issues with the header but still t he issue persists. Any ideas?]

Comment: You may need to explicitly specify that the separator character in your file is a semicolon, rather than a comma (which is what the "C" in "CSV" stands for).

Comment: That is almost certainly the reason, but since you haven't shown us any code, there's no way to help you.

Comment: You have solved it, thanks! It was the separator causing the problem, have a good day!